# Computer starts muted (ubunutu + Xfce)

Tags: ubuntu, audio, xfce, linux-mint

I don't know if this is a linux problem or an xfce one,

Default installation (mint 7) came with Gnome and I don't remember this problem happening then. It only occured after I switched to Xfce,

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed pulse audio (from synaptic) and the problem is fixed!

Based on suggestion (comment #2) from this bug report for ubuntu:
[xfce4-mixer master is always muted at reboot](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-mixer/+bug/378470)